# what are Domains?

Tags: cisco, storage, switch

When we deal with Cisco /  Brocade Fabric switches ,we come across Domains .

What exactly is the purpose of a domain in a switch and how many Domains can we 've ?

Appreciate if some one can give some insight. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Like everything else FC, it's complicated. [Here's an intro article to start with](http://www.enterprisestorageforum.com/sans/features/article.php/3708911/Storage-Networking-Basics-Understanding-Fibre-Channel-Domains.htm).

They're something akin to subnets; a mechanism FC uses to route packets to the correct hardware.

Answer (score 4):

Chris has answered the 'what' question, the 'how many' varies from device to device but for Cisco MDS's running NX-OS 5.0 the domain can be from 1 to 239, so 239 per switch/domain.